# python lambda list filtering with multiple conditions

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter, multiple-conditions

My understanding about filtering lists with lambda is that the filter will return all the elements of the list that return True for the lambda function. In that case, for the following code,

```
inputlist = []
inputlist.append(["1", "2", "3", "a"])
inputlist.append(["4", "5", "6", "b"])
inputlist.append(["1", "2", "4", "c"])
inputlist.append(["4", "5", "7", "d"])

outputlist = filter(lambda x: (x[0] != "1" and x[1] != "2" and x[2] != "3"), inputlist)
for item in outputlist: print(item)
```

The output should be

```
['4', '5', '6', 'b']
['1', '2', '4', 'c']
['4', '5', '7', 'd']
```

But the output that I get is

```
['4', '5', '6', 'b']
['4', '5', '7', 'd']
```

I get the expected output, if I use

```
outputlist = filter(lambda x: (x[0] != "1" or x[1] != "2" or x[2] != "3"), inputlist)
```

What am I doing silly here? Or is my understanding not correct?

Comment: We can't tell whether your understanding is correct, because you haven't told us what you expect the `lambda` function to do. If you join the conditions with `and`, it won't evaluate to `true` unless all conditions are true. If you join the conditions with `or`, it will evaluate to `true` if just one of the conditions is true.

Comment: Now I am really feeling dumb! I think I need to stop working and hit the sack. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x = ['1', '2', '4', 'c']`, so `x[1]=='2'`, which makes the expression `(x[0] != "1" and x[1] != "2" and x[2] != "3")` be evaluated as `False`.

When conditions are joined by `and`, they return `True` only if all conditions are `True`, and if they are joined by `or`, they return `True` when the first among them is evaluated to be `True`.

Answer (score 7):

```
['1', '2', '4', 'c']
```

Fails for condition

```
x[0] != "1"
```

as well as

```
x[1] != "2"
```

Instead of using `or`, I believe the more natural and readable way is:

```
lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2]) != ('1','2','3')
```

Out of curiosity, I compared three methods of, er... comparing, and the results were as expected: slicing lists was the slowest, using tuples was faster, and using boolean operators was the fastest. More precisely, the three approaches compared were

```
list_slice_compare = lambda x: x[:3] != [1,2,3]

tuple_compare = lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2]) != (1,2,3)

bool_op_compare = lambda x: x[0]!= 1 or x[1] != 2 or x[2]!= 3
```

And the results, respectively:

```
In [30]: timeit.Timer(setup="import timeit,random; rand_list = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(4)]; list_slice_compare = lambda x: x[:3] != [1,2,3]", stmt="list_slice_compare(rand_list)").repeat()
Out[30]: [0.3207617177499742, 0.3230015148823213, 0.31987868894918847]

In [31]: timeit.Timer(setup="import timeit,random; rand_list = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(4)]; tuple_compare = lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2]) != (1,2,3)", stmt="tuple_compare(rand_list)").repeat()
Out[31]: [0.2399928924012329, 0.23692036176475995, 0.2369164465619633]

In [32]: timeit.Timer(setup="import timeit,random; rand_list = [random.randint(1,9) for _ in range(4)]; bool_op_compare = lambda x: x[0]!= 1 or x[1] != 2 or x[2]!= 3", stmt="bool_op_compare(rand_list)").repeat()
Out[32]: [0.144389363900018, 0.1452672728203197, 0.1431527621755322]
```

Comment: If you use a list on the right side of the `!=`, you could then use a slice on the left side `x[:3] != ["1", "2", "3"]`

Answer (score 5):

The filter is acting exactly like it should.  In the first case

```
lambda x: (x[0] != "1" and x[1] != "2" and x[2] != "3")
```

the filter only "accepts" lists whose first element is not 1 AND whose second element is not 2 AND whose third element is not 3.  Thus the list `['1', '2', '4', 'c']` will not make it through because its first element is 1.  On the contrary,

```
lambda x: (x[0] != "1" or x[1] != "2" or x[2] != "3")
```

will accept any list whose first element is not 1 or whose second element is not 2 or whose third element is not 3.  Thus, `['1', '2', '4', 'c']` will be accepted because its third element is not 3.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `['1', '2', '4', 'c']` doesn't satisfy the condition that `x[0] != "1"`, nor does it satisfy the condition that `x[1] != "2"`.